# Is there any reason to not limit a games framerate to your monitors refresh rate?

Tags: pc, framerate

The title mostly speaks for itself: For example on a 60Hz monitor, do I get any benefit from >60FPS?

I am aware of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221423/is-there-any-reason-to-limit-my-fps), which asks for the exact opposite, and the accepted answer states some advantages of capping your framerate. I want to know whether there are any advantages of *not* capping your framerate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why set framerate higher than your display's?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162140/why-set-framerate-higher-than-your-displays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of advantages:

- Reduced input lag (the time between pressing a button, and seeing the game react to it).
  This requires V-sync to be turned off, which may cause heavy [tearing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/198195/46740).
- You always see the newest state of the game.
  This requires either V-sync to be turned off, or Triple Buffering to be enabled.

As you can probably tell from the accepted answer in the question you linked to, unlocking the framerate comes at the cost of higher power consumption, higher heat generation, and may result in higher noise production.

Whether the advantages are worth it, is different from person to person.